# Is AutoHotkey capable of defining Arrays in a zero based order?

Tags: arrays, object, prototype, autohotkey

I've often been frustrated by the fact that AutoHotkey is not a zero based language. It doesn't match well when you are translating code from other languages, or even interacting with them such as in JScript through [COM ScriptControl](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=474&sid=4759add3be1efeca0870babea3ca0dd6#p474). Even parsing DOM elements you have to account for them being zero based, it just seems that most languages have adopted zero based arrays.

Now you can declare an array and make it zero based by doing this:

```
arr := []
arr[0] := 1
```

The above works, if I asked for arr[0] it would return 1. But if I use length() method it returns 0, even though there is a value in there!

If we declare and then push():

```
arr := []
arr.push(3)
```

It's always stored starting from 1, I want this changed!

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because AutoHotkey is a prototype OOP language (like JavaScript) you can override any function, even built in ones. Below is demonstration of overriding Array(), which according to [Lexikos](https://github.com/Lexikos) is an undocumented fact that it overrides defining an array as such [].

I didn't believe it possible as there are several threads on the forums asking for zero based to implemented natively, but none offered a solution. Even the thread where an override of Array() was demonstrated made no mention that this would be possible!

As a bonus, I included split() (zero based StrSplit() function), to help demonstrate further the endless possibilities of this feature.

Just to note, I haven't unit tested or implemented ever method override, it's possible I've overlooked something but I felt it was enough for a proof of concept. Further, I have no doubts that this will affect performance on large arrays, particularly because of how I implemented Length() for this demo.

```
x := [] ; declare empty array
x.push("Zero Based rocks!") ; push message to the array.
msgbox % x[0] 

x := "" ; clear our Object
x := split("AutoHotkey with Zero Based Arrays")
msgbox % x.2 " " x.3 " " x.4 " " x.1 " " x.0 

Array(prm*) {
    x := {}
    loop % prm.length()
        x[A_Index -1] := prm[A_Index]
    x.base := _Array
    return x
}

split(x, dlm:="", opt:="") {
    r := []
    for k,v in StrSplit(x, dlm, opt)
        r.push(v)
    return r
}

Class _Array {

    ; Modified .length() to account for 0 index
    length() {
        c:=0
        for k in this
            c++
        return c
    }

    ; Modified .push() to start at 0
    push(x) {
        if (this.0 == "" && this.length() == 0)
            return this.0 := x
        else
            return this[this.MaxIndex()+1] := x
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice! I'm wondering if there is a magic way to also change the behavior of A_Index.

Comment: Short of messing around with AutoHotkey source code, I don't think there is. Also if you like this check out: https://gist.github.com/errorseven/660178adcc754fd9a7c1b1ff22852167#file-pythahk-ahk